# How to read enviroment variables in dockerfile correctly

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile where i am trying to read runtime args. Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM clojure:openjdk-8-lein-slim-buster
ENV dbconfig ""
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Ddbconfig=${dbconfig}", "-jar", "abc.jar", "server"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

And here is the docker run command where i am passing values at runtime. Am i doing something wrong here? Values are always recognized as null. I have also tried removing `ENV dbconfig ""` but nothing works

```
docker run --rm -e dbconfig='{"somekey" "value"}' xyz/abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to define entrypoint : [exec vs shell](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

> The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use
> double-quotes (“) around words not single-quotes (‘).
> So you use the `exec` form.

[But](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) :

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell.
> This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example,
> ENTRYPOINT [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on
> $HOME

So favor the shell form to allow env variable substitutions :

```
ENTRYPOINT java -Ddbconfig=${dbconfig} -jar abc.jar server
```

or invoke a shell in the exec form :

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java","-Ddbconfig=${dbconfig}", "-jar", "abc.jar", "server" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using CMD to pass runtime arguments, sample like below

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD ["/sample.sh", "argument1","argument2"]
```

Then passing arguments at runtime would be:-

```
docker run -i -t argument1 argument2
```